# How to install Ubuntu Server to a iSCSI Drive using IBFT

Tags: boot, server, iscsi

We have to install Ubuntu Server 16.04 on iSCSI Drives and boot from them, because we have no local storage. We have configured the iSCSI capable Network Controllers to log in into the iSCSI Target and boot from them (Actually i can see the targets when i start the Server). But the installer of ubuntu Server is not able to use this information. He does not configure the Network or the Disk Drives using IBFT (iSCSI Boot Firmware Table). I have to manually create the network Config and then i can configure the iSCSI Targets. Since we want to install in a later step with foreman, this is not a option. Is it possible to use IBFT to tell the installer that he has already a network config and two Drives?

Answer (score 0):

Dorian,

I was able to achieve the requirement in CentOS 7, check my post [Install Ubuntu over iSCSI target ibft nic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/787495/install-ubuntu-over-iscsi-target-ibft-nic)             and   https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=50&t=58155

By the way, I've observed, using ipxe is fast (installation time is less than 5 minutes) instead of iSCSI capable Network Controllers - I am using Intel PRO/1000 MT Server Adapter dual port with iSCSI firmware (installation time is 30 minutes). If possible, please share your performance observation.

Using Intel bootutil tool iSCSI firmware was enabled.